# Take input from form and pass it to function using a wp-plugin

Tags: plugins, php, forms, 500-internal-error

Edit: I have fixed my original issue, please skip to the body for my last remaining issue.

I need to make a plugin. That displays an input field to the user, takes that input field data and passess it to a php function, and then reloads that page and displays what ever the user has typed in.

What I have in my plugin file

```
     function testytest($val1,$val2)
{
        return $val1;
}

    function awepop_add_view() {

           $idPageToTest = 55;


            if (    isset($GLOBALS["post"])
                &&  ($GLOBALS["post"]->ID === $idPageToTest)
            ) {
        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><p style="text-align: center;">

<form action="" method="get">
    Host Name:
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"></input>


    <br></br>
    or
    <br></br>
    Ip Address:
    <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"></input>

    <br></br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"></input>
</form>

</p></div></div></div>';}
    }
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'awepop_add_view', 20 );
    #add_action("wp_head", "awepop_add_view");
    ?>
```

For what ever reason if I add php code to my echo my site hangs with a 500 error until I remove it. It doesn't matter if I put the code above or below my form.

and the code is this

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['submit']) )
{
    //be sure to validate and clean your variables
    $val1 = htmlentities($_GET['val1']);
    $val2 = htmlentities($_GET['val2']);

    //then you can use them in a PHP function. 
    $result = testytest($val1, $val2);
    echo '$result';

}
?>
```

I got it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055115/how-to-pass-form-input-value-to-php-function

I do devops not web stuff Sorry =)

Edit: Now when I hit submit it sends me to my sites homepage, it doesn't reload the page I am on with the users input displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Fist off always enable Debug in Wordpress when developing. Second pay attention to how you start and end quotes. I had a echo ' ' with ' in side of it. Taking that out solved my issue.